# How to upload an image in Visual Studio Resources folder programmatically?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to upload an image into an image box and then save that image in Visual Studio Solution Explorer.  I managed to browse and display the image but I need help to how to save the image.  This is my code and thank you for any help.

```
OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    pbxImage.Load(openFileDialog.FileName);
}
```

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do? What does "save that image in Visual Studio Solution Explorer" mean?

Comment: Are you trying to add a image to the project that is currently in your solution explorer? if yes, you don't need to upload, just update the project file. If no, you can't really "Upload" a image into the solution explorer, because it is not meant for that :-)

Comment: As I just said, I need to save that image in Solution Explorer, available for next time.  If you have another solution I wont mind, I just need last image to be available next time the user open the application.

Comment: *Solution Explorer* exists only within visual studio whilst writing the application, if you want to save for next time either store the path somewhere (xml file) or copy the image to a known location.

Comment: @AlexK.  Copy the image to a location can be good.  Can you please give some info on how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the comments I can direct you toward what you can do to achieve : Having an image available on the next time that the program is ran.

**You cannot add an Image to your visual studio solution programmatically.**

That being said what you can do is :

- (optional) Save the image in the application's folder so that if the original is deleted you still have it
- Save the path of the image in a text file (raw text, xml, json) the format is your choice.
- When the program loads,  read the text file and load the images

If you save the images in a specific folder, you can also simply loop through all of the files in that folder to load all of the saved images instead of having to save the paths in a text file.

To save the image you can use :

```
using System.IO;

if(!Directory.Exists(@"path to your images directory"))
    Directory.Create(@"path to your images directory");

File.Copy(@"original path", @"destination path");
```

The original path here is the path to the image you want to save. Knowing you allready loaded an image using a file dialog i'm assumming you know how to get this path. And then to load the images when the program is ran :

```
foreach(string img in Directory.GetFiles(@"path to your images directory"))
{
    code to load your images (img is the path as a string)
}
```

Comment: The first option sounds interesting.  Can you please give me some hint on how to do that?